# Passing a pointer when a reference is required

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have the following 2 functions:

```
void B::set(A * ptr){
  this->a = ptr;
  this->info = get_some_info_from_a(*ptr);
}

T get_some_info_from_a(A& ref){
  return ref.info;
}
```

As you see, I have A * ptr as a pointer in set(...), but I would need a reference to call get_some_info_from_a(...). So I dereference ptr and give it as an argument.

Is that correct? Is it efficient given A has some resources which must be copied by a copy/move constructor? I ask the question because it really seems that this line introduces some mysterious bugs.

Comment: Nope, it's fine. nothing will be copied.

Comment: `get_some_info_from_a` never accesses the `ref` argument, but returns a global variable named `info`. Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @Frxstrem I think the real code would work out `info` from `ref`.

Comment: Oh, that's embarassing. Of course info would be taken from ref. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's correct and efficient. Performing indirection with `*ptr` just gets you the value that `ptr` points to and then you are passing that by reference to `get_some_info_from_a`. That value is never copied.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine and will *not* invoke any copy/move ctor as you are calling by *reference*.  However, a `const` or two (if a member function) in the function signature wouldn't go a miss:

```
T get_some_info_from_a(const A& ref) const {
```